# How to secure $_POST of php without making quotes and other things

Tags: php, tinymce

I have tinyMCE editor which is passing data to php processing file.

If I use `$variable=$_POST(['tinyMCE_textarea']);` everything is ok.
But I want to secure it so nothing bad will come from user who entered some data into textarea.

And when I use `$variable=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST(['tinyMCE_textarea']));`
The result becomes dammaged with some `\"` signs. So how can I add maximum security without changing the variable ?

Comment: How do you want to "secure" it? Are you trying to protect against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: yes and againts other possible threats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyMCE is able to clean up data, however it is critical that you don't rely on client-side stuff.

To secure data for database, you use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  The result is intended for use with mysql and not for display.

To secure data for display, you use the `htmlspecialchars()` function.  htmlentities() also works but would convert all applicable entities, so for security you only need htmlspecialchars().

So the simplified picture is

```
.// Insert to database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (content) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['tinyMCE_textarea'] ) . "')");

.// Display to user - doesn't matter whether the data is from post or database
echo htmlspecialchars ( $_POST['tinyMCE_textarea'] );
```

Comment: I recommend storing the value in a variable so you're not directly dealing with the $_POST variable

Comment: thanks a lot! Another question, you suggest me everything that comes from user to enter to database the way you wrote ? I mean it works fine, but is it the right way to add mysql_real_escape_string to each variable while updating or inserting data into mysql ?

Comment: Please write a simple example from getting variable via POST to storing it into mysql. But with the best reliable way, simple and easy , and of course secure

Comment: Yes David. All user-inputted text that goes to the database should be escaped.  Some data can be validated by casting to int / double or by regular expression, but otherwise the escaping is mandatory.  And as kjetilh said you probaly want to store the post to a variable first for readibility.

Answer (score 1):

use prepared statement or PDO.
use htmlentities() or covert atleast '<' and '<' '"' to "& gt;" and so ..

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to escape the user input before outputting (using for example `htmlentities()`) and escape the string before storing it in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL parameter binding, and you are safe from any injection.